# How to Design method to Program & Calibrate a Panel of PCBs

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, manufacturing, calibration, manufacturing-process

I'm designing a sensor-package PCB which needs to be programmed and calibrated while still in a panel of 10.

I'd like to avoid a large bed-of-nails type setup for this step so that the panel can easily be fit into a calibration chamber and not be obstructed.

My first guess is to route some signals from each PCB onto the panel to some sort of edge connector. But from what I've read: some people try to avoid this due to risks of shorts and traces being ripped up when de-panelizing.

Have you solved a similar problem? If so, how? Are there any other options which I'm not considering?

Comment: im not expert to answer, but sharing my 3 thoughts related to the short traces..

1.  you can have different signals going out through different corners of pcb ..
2.  you can route on different far layers.. ie top and bottom .. 
3. you can put some hole between tracks to have some barrier near the copper fracture

Comment: You might want to reconsider a bed-of-nails solution.

Comment: A well designed pogo pin solution isn't going to add much to footprint, and only maybe 3-4 cm to height.  What adds space is a lever actuated press type setup, but if you're dealing with a panel you're probably setting it in some fixture anyway, and just need to add some hold down latches.

Comment: One important piece of info I left out is that the sensor to be calibrated is a contactless temperature sensor. I'm concerned that a bed-of-nails solution would obstruct the field of view and block the black-body calibration surface.